# NAVIGATIONBAR Swift perzonalizado

Tags: swift, xcode

Mi objetivo es poder agregarle al navigationBar una barra lateral que sea de color diferente actualmente se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera lograr algo asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
    func setupNavigationBar(showBack:Bool, showMenu:Bool,isLogin:Bool)
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

        var leftItemTitle = UIBarButtonItem()
        var backgroundItem = UIBarButtonItem()


        let sizeLength = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 2
        let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeLength, height: 70)

        let mediumView = UIView()
        let frame = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size
        mediumView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame!.width,  height: frame!.height)
        mediumView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = self.menuText
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()



        leftItemTitle = UIBarButtonItem(customView: titleLabel)


        if(!showBack && !showMenu && !isLogin){
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.removeAll()
            self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false);
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Utils.Color.LigthViewBackGround
        }
        else if(showBack){
            let backMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "backButton"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(backPressed))
            backMenuButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.white
            backMenuButtonItem.width = CGFloat(30)

            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backMenuButtonItem,leftItemTitle,]
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Utils.Color.backgroundBlue

        }
        else if(showMenu){
            let sideMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "sideMenu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(sideMenuPressed))
            sideMenuButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.white
            sideMenuButtonItem.width = CGFloat(30)

            let vistaAzul = UIView(frame: CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 30 ))
            vistaAzul.backgroundColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText


//            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(vistaAzul)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [sideMenuButtonItem,leftItemTitle]

        }
        else if (isLogin){
               self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Utils.Color.backgroundLogin
        }




        if let hidden = navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden
        {
            if(hidden)
            {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
            }
            else
            {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: hacer eso no es posible en IOS, al menos no con el navigationController. deberias presentar el viewcontroller en cuestion y poner una vista personalizada en la parte superior con contrains que contenga el fondo blanco y un boton para ir atras y el label con el titulo de la pagina.

Comment: ok crea el chat

Comment: @kjoe este es el chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98049/swift entra porfavor

Comment: @kjoe parece que no es tan difícil. Bruno, [aquí](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar) hay algunas indicaciones para personalizar la barra de navegación. [Aquí también hay un tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/dyqrfa/customize-navigation-bar-appearance-with-swift) del que te puedes ayudar para hacer tu personalización.

Comment: Le voy a mirar estos links que me envias @A.Cedano gracias por la ayuda!, se aprecia de corazon

Comment: el problema no es que sea difícil o no sino que no debería hacerlo, no es común para los usuarios de iOS tener un nabigation bar así, es un diseño de android, y no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: @kjoe entiendo lo que dices aunque como no es un proyecto personal, necesito poder replicarlo pense hasta poner una imagen que sea asi aunque me gustaria algo mas limpio, si tienes alguna idea de como lograrlo me gustaria, probe poner un degradees pero el mismo no queda con los colores nitidos

Comment: para replicar esa imagen que pones exactamente no debería usar un navigation controller, podrías crear tu mismo los componentes, poner una vista en blanco y agregarle el titulo así como los botones y hacer el dismiss tu mismo.

Comment: @kjoe sera que soy bastante nobato en el tema peor me puedes guiar mas especificamente como crear los componentes ah que te refieres con mas exactitud?

Comment: la idea es que este viewcontroller lo muestres como un modal con fullscreen presentation y que pongas los elementos que representan tu vista un botón para ir atrás y tienes que añadirle un target, y poner un vista en blanco, y el titulo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar esta libreria `MDCAppBarViewController`, lo instalas en los pods y listo.

Adjunto el link para una mejor información.

https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/ios